# Verilog Reg/Wire Confusion

Tags: verilog, logical-operators, cpu-registers

I'm making a Multicycle CPU in Verilog that consists of a Datapath and a Control. The outputs of the control (state machine) are registers, but the connections between the datapath are wires. If a wire signal is supposed to be (in psuedo-code): `wire = OR(wire coming from a mux, reg output from control)`, how do I do this? Can you OR a wire with a reg in Verilog? If not is there a better way to implement this? Can the control signal outputs be registers in the control module, but wires in the top module?

Update with picture for clarification:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can or a wire and a reg output in Verilog.

Yes, each sub-module's outputs, which are essentially wires, can be directly or indirectly internally connected to a reg within the sub-module.

I think that is a fine way to do it.

Now, you can even declare the outputs of a module to be "reg", but that is just semantic sugar over declaring the output and reg separately. I like the explicit way better (i.e. q1_o and q1_reg).

```
module Submod(input clk_i, intput d_i, output q1_o, output reg q2_o);
    reg q1_reg;
    always @(posedge clk_i) begin
        q1_reg <= d_i;
        q2_o <= ~d_i;
    end
    assign q1_o = q1_reg;
endmodule

module Main(input clk_i, input [3:0]ext_i, output [1:0]ext_o)
    wire mux, x1, x2;

    Submod Submod_inst(clk_i, ext_i[0], x1, x2);

    assign ext_o[0] = x1;
    assign mux = ext_i[1] ? ext_i[2] : ext_i[3];

    assign ext_o[1] = mux | x2; /* something like this */
endmodule
```

Comment: FYI: example is notional. I think the syntax is right it is of the top of my head and  I don't have access to a Verilog compiler to check. It should be close enough to see what is going on with how the regs can be hooked to wires.