# Verilog : Assigning ONE wire high in a vector and rest low?

Tags: verilog, fpga

On an FPGA, instead of using a register, eg;

```
module FooReg(output wire o_foo, input wire [1:0] i_address);

  parameter FOO_MSB = 3;

  reg [FOO_MSB:0] r_data = 0;

  assign o_foo = r_data[FOO_MSB]; // OUTPUT HEAD OF FOO

  always @(*)
  begin
    r_data            = 0;        // RESET DATA VECTOR
    r_data[i_address] = 1'b1;     // SET ADDRESSED ELEMENT OF VECTOR
  end
endmodule // FooReg
```

but is there a way to achieve the SAME functionality using just NETs?

For instance;

```
module FooNet(output wire o_foo, input wire [1:0] i_address);

  parameter FOO_MSB = 3;

  wire [FOO_MSB:0] w_data = (w_data[i_address] is 1'b1) BUT REST ARE 1'b0; // <------

  assign o_foo = w_data[FOO_MSB]; // OUTPUT HEAD OF FOO

endmodule // FooNet
```

Excuse me if the answer is obvious.... but in my ACTUAL verilog the data can be 256-bits wide and addressed using 8-bits or larger and I'm trying to avoid tying up storage if it can be done with wiring alone and I'm still learning to use FPGAs... (and I stand corrected that this is ALL combinatorial logic anyhow so are equivalent under the hood anyhow, due to my misunderstanding of the significance of 'reg' for which I am grateful.)

Comment: something like `w_data = 256'b1 << i_address` ?

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. A senior moment strikes me again!

Answer (score 1):

**You are NOT using/making registers!**

The `reg` keyword is misleading. It does no mean you make one or more registers The 'reg' keyword is needed if you assign to the variable in an always section.

You only instance a register if you follow on of the standard register templates `always @(posedge clk) ....`.

Note that in System Verilog the names `wire` and `reg` are replaced with the keyword  'logic' and you can still use the exact same syntax you have used.

I have added comment to you code using the "//>>>" markers

```
reg [FOO_MSB:0] r_data = 0;

  assign o_foo = r_data[FOO_MSB]; // OUTPUT HEAD OF FOO

  //>>> The section below generates a combinatorial circuit 
  //>>> and as such you only get logic or wires out of this.
  always @(*)
  begin
    //>>> No you are NOT resetting a register here
    //>>> Your setting a vector (a bundle of wires) wire to all zeros 
    r_data            = 0;        // RESET REGISTER
    //>>> One of the wires is not zero but one
    r_data[i_address] = 1'b1;     // SET REQUESTED BIT
  end
endmodule // FooRegister //>>> And change the name because no registers are made here :-)
```

See also [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988353/verilog-reg-wire-confusion?rq=1)